# Choose various entries from a list if its key occurs in another list and add strings together

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a question regarding my dataframe. In one column, for each row, I have a list of relevant persons (personlist) and a list of persons' speeches (speech) (both relevant and irrelevant persons' speeches). Now, I want to choose the speeches of the relevant persons (from personlist), where the info whether they are relevant is given within the list (personlist) in another column and subsequently add all their speeches together while ignoring the irrelevant speeches. So one column provides the list with last names I am looking for and the other column provides a list of all speakers (first and last name) and their speech and I want to create a new column where the speeches of the relevant persons are added (separated by a space) and stored in the respective row.

So my initial dataset looks like this:

```
ticker  year    quarter personlist              jobposition speech
xx      2009    1       ("Angle", "Barth")      CEO         [("Mike Angle", "Thank you"), ("Barbara Barth", "It is"), ("Will Cook", "Yes, true")]
xx      2009    1       ("Angle", "Barth")      CFO         [("Mike Angle", "Thank you"), ("Barbara Barth", "It is"), ("Will Cook", "Yes, true")]
xx      2009    2       ("Angle", "Barth")      CEO         [("Mike Angle", "I am surprised"), ("Barbara Barth", "So am I"), ("Will Cook", "Me too")]
xx      2009    2       ("Angle", "Barth")      CFO         [("Mike Angle", "I am surprised"), ("Barbara Barth", "So am I"), ("Will Cook", "Me too")]
yy      2008    3       ("Cruz", "Dolm")        CEO         [("Damien Cruz", "Hello"), ("Lara Dolm", "Nice to meet you"), ("Lara Bel", "You too")]
yy      2008    3       ("Cruz", "Dolm")        CFO         [("Damien Cruz", "Hello"), ("Lara Dolm", "Nice to meet you"), ("Lara Bel", "You too")]
```

For row one for instance, I want to check each key-value pair whether the first list entry ends with one of the last names in personlist, if no continue, if yes, take the speech part (i.e. value to the entry) and store it in new column, repeat it for the others and add the matches together. As such, I want the following dataset (I hid the initial column speech here, but it should still be contained, so I do not want to replace it, just create a new column).

```
ticker  year    quarter personlist               relevantspeeches
xx      2009    1       ("Angle", "Barth")       "Thank you It is"
xx      2009    1       ("Angle", "Barth")       "Thank you It is"
xx      2009    2       ("Angle", "Barth")       "I am surprised So am I"
xx      2009    2       ("Angle", "Barth")       "I am surprised So am I"
yy      2008    3       ("Cruz", "Dolm")         "Hello Nice to meet you"
yy      2008    3       ("Cruz", "Dolm")         "Hello Nice to meet you"
```

Could someone help me how to solve this?

Thank you!! Julia

Answer (score 0):

with comprehension list and apply method :

```
def select(row):
    return " ".join([said for person in row.personlist
    for name,said in row.speech if person in name])

df['relevant'] = df.apply(select,axis=1)
```

`df.relevant` is then :

```
"""
0           Thank you It is
1           Thank you It is
2    I am surprised So am I
3    I am surprised So am I
4    Hello Nice to meet you
5    Hello Nice to meet you
Name: relevant, dtype: object
"""
```